# understanding transforms: resize and centercrop with same size

Tags: pytorch, image-augmentation

I am trying to understand this particular set of compose  transforms:

```
transform= transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224) interpolation=torchvision.transforms.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),\
transforms.CenterCrop(224),transforms.ToTensor(),\
transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
```

Does it make sense (and is it legit) to do centercrop after transforms - with the same size parameter? I would have thought resize itself is giving the `centercrop` but I see in the repos that centercrop is composed after resize - both with exactly the same sizes. I wonder what is the use of doing such a thing. For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that my input image sizes vary (ie they are all not of the same dims).

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have thought resize itself is giving the center crop.

Function [`T.Resize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) won't center crop your image, the center will stay the same since you are only resizing the original image, *i.e.* proportions are kept and the original center remains at the center. Applying a crop of the same shape as the image - since it's just after the resize - with [`T.CenterCrop`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop) doesn't make any difference since you are cropping nothing out of the image.

If you change the sizes of your `T.CenterCrop`, *then* this and the order you apply both transforms will matter greatly.

Comment: thank you for this awesome explanation. So, as things stand, in the transform I have shown, `CenterCrop` will have no effect since it is of the same size as resize and is applied directly after resize. Is my understanding correct? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried looking w/ and w/o it?

Comment: I did and I did not see a difference - but, since I was looking at an image, I was unsure if it did something or not (as you can imagine). Hence my question (more of a paranoid clarification)